# Passing and returning an array between HTML and Google Apps Script

Tags: html, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a search bar for a Google Sheet using Google Apps Script and HTML. Essentially, I take the user's search input from a form (name, date, and keywords) and pass it over to my GScript file to do the searching. I want an array of indexes containing the rows of the sheet that match the search criteria. I know that the actual search part of the script works; however, my problem comes when passing the array of integers back into HTML.

Right now, I have it so that I initialize an empty array on the HTML side of my code and pass it to the GScript. It should return the array and then I check if the length of the array is empty. However, I get an error message saying: "Cannot read property "length" from null."

```
function gatherSearch() {

      clearErrorWarnings();

      var responsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;
      var datefrom = formatDate(document.getElementById('datefrom').value);
      var dateto = formatDate(document.getElementById('dateto').value);
      var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
      var searchRowMatch = [];


      if(checkValidSearch(responsible, datefrom, dateto, description)) {
        searchRowMatch = google.script.run.basicSearch(responsible, datefrom, dateto, description, searchRowMatch);
        if(searchRowMatch.length == 0) {
          noSearchMatch();
        }
      }
    }
```

I understand there's something about the GScript running asynchronously with HTML or something along those lines? Any pointer in the right direction or explanation on how to fix this would be great :) Thanks!

Comment: `gs.run()` doesn't return the executed function's return value, but returns a script runner object, which is useless for what you want to do. Use `withSuccessHandler()`.

Comment: See withSuccessHandler in this article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Pretty simple fix, just added the withSuccessHandler() tag

```
if(checkValidSearch(responsible, datefrom, dateto, description)) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).basicSearch(responsible, datefrom, dateto, description, searchRowMatch);
}
```